# how can I pass a variable into a script from the command line?

Tags: coffeescript

Let's say I'm running a script at the command line:

```
coffee ./scripts/doSomeStuff.coffee
```

where doSomeStuff.coffee looks like:

```
numberOfTimes = ??? 

doStuff = (times) -> 
  while times > 0 
    console.log('doing stuff') 
    --times 

doStuff(numberOfTimes)
```

How can I pass in the number of times to do stuff via the command line? `--eval` seemed like the obvious choice but adding `--eval='global.numberOfTimes=5'` didn't help.

I can do it with `export REPEAT_TIMES=5` from bash but that seems rife with potential side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way you do with node.js, via `process.argv`

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Command:

```
coffee ./scripts/doSomeStuff.coffee 5
```

CoffeeScript:

```
numberOfTimes = process.argv[2]
# index 0 is the interpreter: coffee
# index 1 is the file: ./scripts/doSomeStuff.coffee
# index 2 is the first argument: 5
```

There are also a great number of [`npm` modules](https://npmjs.org/search?q=argv) that provide nicer interfaces for parsing `argv`. I've had a good time with [optimist](https://npmjs.org/package/optimist) myself.

Comment: PLease don't insert code into other peoples answers.  I don't want to look like I recommended your way of setting a default, because that's pretty convoluted.  That should very simply be: `numberOfTimes = process.argv[2] ? 1`

Comment: You're right I hadn't run that code yet, forgot about the simpler way. I think adding that makes a more complete answer though so I added it.